# Polymer 1.x: Accessing properties set from inside one property

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

From ***inside*** a *published property* I want to access all the published properties of the Polymer object with a ***single variable*** instead of listing them all out. e.g., `foo, bar, baz, ...`

I tried using the variable, `this.properties`. Which works ***outside*** the `properties` property (e.g., the `_show` function) but does not work ***inside*** it (e.g., `quux`).

[Here is the jsBin](http://jsbin.com/bihaqilayu/1/edit?html,output).

I expect to see:

> qux: lorem ipsum dolor
>
> quux: lorem ipsum dolor

But I actually see:

> qux: lorem ipsum dolor
>
> quux:

Please provide a working jsBin to show how to accomplish this.

http://jsbin.com/bihaqilayu/1/edit?html,output

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
</head>
<body>

<dom-module id="x-element">

<template>
  <style>
    :host {
      font-family: roboto, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
  <paper-button on-tap="_show">Show in Console</paper-button>
  <div>qux: [[qux]]</div>
  <div>quux: [[quux]]</div>
</template>

<script>
  (function(){
    Polymer({
      is: "x-element",
      properties: {
        qux: {
          // This works. Trying to repeat below using quux,
          // but using a single variable, without listing all the properties
          computed: '_computeQux(foo, bar, baz)'
        },
        quux: {
          // This is the problematic line
          computed: '_computeQuux(this.properties)'
          /** /
          The following also do not work:
          computed: '_computeQuux(this)'
          computed: '_computeQuux(properties)'
          computed: '_computeQuux(element.properties)'
          /**/
        },
        foo: {
          type: String,
          value: 'lorem',
        },
        bar: {
          type: String,
          value: 'ipsum',
        },
        baz: {
          type: String,
          value: 'dolor',
        },
      },
      _computeQux: function(a, b, c){
        return [a, b, c].join(' ');
      },
      _computeQuux: function(ob){
        return [ ob.foo.value ,
                 ob.bar.value ,
                 ob.baz.value ].join(' ');
      },
      _show: function(){
        console.log(this.properties);
      }
    });
  })();
</script>

</dom-module>

<x-element></x-element>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not how computed works... it only works with properties, not arbitrary values named in the string... You probably want to use a getter() or just a custom method to achieve this, a getter approach is illustrated here: http://jsbin.com/hakajiwamu/edit?html,console,output

For what it's worth, the reason you *should* list all the property names is because computed methods only fire when all the properties are defined.

ie:

```
computed: 'someFunc(a, b, c)'
```

will only fire once all of this.a|b|c != undefined

This is to avoid extraneous calls as each value is set and is clearly explained [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#computed-properties) after the first code example